# How to use local variable of Page_OnLoad method in OnClick event in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, onload-event

I am designing a website in which I need to update a table Company in my database through CompanyDetails page with respect to the auto increment field CompanyID which is being passed through Query string from previous page named Company and only one button is there for insert and update. So my problem is I am unable to get the value of Companyid of Page_OnLoad event in SaveButtonClick event.

Note: I have already tried Session and View state, IsPostBack but in Onclick event even their value are not being maintained and are updated to 0 or null.

Here is my code......(Please ignore my coding mistakes)

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class CompanyDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int Companyid = 0;
    string cmdName = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Companyid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CompanyID"]);
            cmdName = Request.QueryString["CommandType"];
            Session["something"] = Companyid;
        }
            if (cmdName == "Details")
            {
                BindTextBoxvalues();
            }
    }

    protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = Session["something"].ToString();
        try
        {
            if (SaveButton.Text == "Save")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                String mycon = "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=something; Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
                cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertCompany", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CompanyCode.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LegalName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LegalName.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaxID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TaxID.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BusinessPhone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BusinessPhone.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Extension", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Extension.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FaxNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FaxNumber.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Description.Value;
                bool isstatus = IsActiveCheckBox.Checked;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(isstatus);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Saved Successfully.');window.location='Company.aspx';</script>");
            }
            else if (SaveButton.Text == "Update")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                String mycon = "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=something; Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("spUpdateCompany", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(Companyid);
              // I need the value here but it is being updated to zero here.
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Companyid;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CompanyCode.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BusinessPhone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BusinessPhone.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Extension", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Extension.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FaxNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FaxNumber.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaxID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TaxID.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LegalName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LegalName.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Updated Successfully.');window.location='Company.aspx';</script>");
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message",
                "alert('Oops!! following error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
        }

    }
    protected void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Company.aspx");
    }
    private void BindTextBoxvalues()
    {
        SaveButton.Text = "Update";
        string constr = "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=something; Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Company where CompanyID=" + Companyid, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        Name.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
        CompanyCode.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
        LegalName.Text = dt.Rows[0][15].ToString();
        TaxID.Text = dt.Rows[0][14].ToString();
        BusinessPhone.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
        Extension.Text = dt.Rows[0][13].ToString();
        FaxNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0][12].ToString();
        Description.Value = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
        IsActiveCheckBox.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0][11]);
    }
}
```

Comment: your only saving the variable on the first page hit.  Take your code setting the variable out of the !IsPostback and put it as the first line of code in the page_load

Comment: I have tried that but if I am doing so then also it is updated to null. I basically want that On Insert CommandType the textboxes should be empty and if CommandType is Details then textboxes should be populated via BindTextBoxvalues() this method.

Comment: so companyid is null when you get to the BindTestBoxValues?

Comment: Also,  have you tried using the Request.QueryString["CompanyID"] value directly in the save routine? The querystring object is still available on each postback so you dont have to save it in a variable.  I would check the value of the querystring object to make sure its got a value

Comment: no it is null in BindTextBoxValues but in SaveButton_Click event

Comment: yes I have tried that still it turned out to be null

Comment: are you getting the companyid on the initial page hit in the querystring?  It sounds like the value is never even being set and its always null.

Comment: Yes, I am getting correct value of Companyid in Page_Load event as well as BindTextBoxValues()

Comment: i would set a breakpoint in the save routine and check the value of the querystring object and see if its still present.  I would use that instead of trying to use the variables everywhere.

Comment: I did that after posting this question. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: It looks like you gave the credit to someone else when i gave you the answer in the very first comment i made.   :-(     please uptick my first comment so i get credit for helping

Comment: Sorry for that, I am new here I am unaware of these things. Can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: just hover your mouse over my comment and an up arrow will show up on the left side of the comment.  Just click the arrow

Comment: No arrow is being displayed on mouse hover over your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any values stored in local variables need to be read from Request on every postback.

So do following

```
int Companyid = 0;
string cmdName = null;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        Companyid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CompanyID"]);
        cmdName = Request.QueryString["CommandType"];


        if (!IsPostBack)
          {
            if (cmdName == "Details")// be sure about string case
            {
                BindTextBoxvalues();
            }
        }
}
```

Or make viewstate properties

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you so much, now the code is working as per the requirement. I have marked it as answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your property available on the PostBack, do not use !IsPostBack

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Companyid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CompanyID"]);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that but if I am doing so then also it is updated to null. I basically want that On Insert CommandType the textboxes should be empty and if CommandType is Details then textboxes should be populated via BindTextBoxvalues() this method

Comment: Then you need to investigate why it's null with some debugging.  The query string parameter will not change on PostBack on the same page.  It only changes if you change it in code or go to a different page.

Comment: I am sorry I have done debugging also but I am not able to find any solution.